# C - reading a file and segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, file, readfile

Im writing a program in C (eclipse in linux) so I need to open a big text file and read it (and than try with diffrent size of buffer each time)

Anyways, this is the code and I don't understand why Im getting segmentation fault from the open function

```
int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char* buff[67108864];
    FILE *testfile;
    double dif;
    fd = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd>=0) {
        read(fd,buff,67108864);
        close(fd);      }

    return 0;
}
```

I have edited my question but now if I change my buffer to the biggest size I need (67108864 bytes) im still getting segmentation fault...

Comment: `if (ferror(testfile))`, errr, `testfile` is an uninitialised pointer.

Comment: and `fclose(testfile)`

Comment: @DanielFischer so what should be instead?

Comment: Err. fd>0 should be fd>=0 of course... What on earth is going on with the testfile variable (not much!)? Not to mention the "unusual" behaviour of using a buffer of size 1!

Comment: `fopen, fread, fwrite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well if you want to allocate memory into buff, you need to make it a pointer..

```
char* buff;
```

also notice you only allocate one char.. you should consider that, I think you want to use more memory..

another common thing is not using dynamic memory for file reading..

try:

```
char buff[100];
```

and then just the same code...

```
read(fd,buff,100));
```

and then just keep reading until the find is complete, read returns the amount of bytes actually read.

Also like commented above, you are using testfile before initializing it.. that is also an access violation

Comment: Depends on the expected contents of the file though.

Comment: and than when I asked to change the buffer size I just need to change the 100 to any size I want?

Comment: yup, I would make it a defenition.. remember you might need to read from the file a few times until it is over

Comment: @Alon Thanks Alon I think it's working now.. but how can I change so I read from the while few times??

Comment: read returns the amount of bytes read, or you can ask if it not reached eof

Answer (score 4):

```
char buff;
```

should be a pointer

```
char *buff;
```

Also after reading `read(fd,buff,(sizeof(char)));` you should allocate more memory to buff with realloc.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
char* buff[67108864]
```

to

```
char buff[67108864]
```

what you need is a char array, not a char point array.