# Buffer size and reading from a file

Tags: c, linux

I already asked a similiar question but I think now the problem is different..
Im writing in C on eclipse ,linux machine.

I need to read the testfile and each time to try with different buffer size...
I know I need to run on the buffer several times if the size of the buffer is too small but im not sure how to do this...

this is my code ( when im running on buffer with size 67108864 im getting segmentation fault.
 * I edited my code

```
int main(void)
{   int fd;
    char* buff = malloc (67108864);
    if (buff){
    fd = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        while (read(fd,buff,67108864)!=0){}
        close(fd);
    }
    }
free(buff);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works fine on my machine , 67108864 is 2**26 and since your datatype is char(1 byte) it is just 64MB and should work fine. You may want to check for the return value of 'read' function which is -1 on errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a `char[]`:

```
char* buff[67108864];
```

but is an array of `char*`. Change to:

```
char buff[67108864];
```

Also, the size of `buff` may be too large for the stack. The typical size of the stack is 1MB (1048576 bytes) but the size of `buff` far exceeds (64MB!) that which would result in a stack overflow error. If you wish to use a buffer of this dynamically allocate it, using [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), and release it later, using [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

```
char* buff = malloc(67108864);
if (buff)
{
    /* Use 'buff' and then release it. */

    free(buff);
}
```

Comment: @Bobbbaa, I suspect you were advised to make buff a `char*`, not a `char*[]` and use dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: In your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617949/c-reading-a-file-and-segmentation-fault) you used `malloc` - btw, you should consider to undo the edit you applied to the earlier question since it makes the answers confusing

Comment: Thanks, anyway I edited my code here... can you guys tell me if this looks ok now??

Answer (score 3):

Remove `*`, you are declaring an array of pointers, but you need an array of characters.

```
   char buff[67108864];
```

*I'm not sure about `67108864` it's too big for stack. Try to make it on heap.*